# Python PIL size Image.new too big

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a project where I need to concatenate a lot of images (80282). Each image is 256 x 256 pixels. Everything is working well for a 20000 by 20000 image, however when I try to create a bigger one like this, it's not working:

```
width = 75264
height = 70144
new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))
```

It tells me:

```
struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <== 4294967295
```

I guess the size of the image I create in order to paste my other images inside is too big ? Does someone have a solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: 75264 by 70144 with 32bpp color depth is approximately 21.5GB of image data. I suggest you search for alternative solutions.

Comment: And by "alternative solutions" I don't just mean different ways to create an image of that size - I mean look for a solution to your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that doesn't involve creating such an image.

Comment: Yes I was trying today to create images of 20000 by 20000 and paste them together afterwards. Do you think it could work ? My images have only 4 colors max and not many in one picture, there is a lot of blanck. Actually, it's just images of traffic so crimson, red, orange or green. A 10000 by 10000 final image is around 35 Mo.